# invoking an action of popup menu in Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In my current project, a developer writes high-level specifications in Domain specific language and then compiles this specification and generate code in target programming language such as Java and Android. The developer writes mainly there four specification (as shown in the image below) : `vocab.mydsl`, `arch.mydsl`, `interaction.mydsl`, and `deploy.mydsl`.

[image]

Now, to compile each specification file separately, I have developed **a pop-up menu in Eclipse Plugin**. For your reference, I am showing a pop-up menu for vocabulary specification. Here, the developer makes a right click, then he goes to **IoTSuite** pop-up menu, then further down to **Compile Domain Spec** pop-up menu.

[image]

Here, the problem is all four pop-up menus are appearing when I right click on `vocab.mydsl`. Ideally, when I make a right-click on `vocab.mydsl`, it should **only** show **compile domain spec** pop-up menu. Similar way, when I make a right click on `arch.mydsl`, it should **only** show **compile Architecture Spec** pop up menu. This applies to other specifications to also.

How should I enable this feature in the Eclipse Plugin? Please let me know in case you need more information to get clarity further.

The content of plugin.xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>

   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus">
      <objectContribution
            objectClass="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile"
            id="org.example.helloworld.contribution1">
         <menu
               label="IoTSuite"
               path="additions"
               id="org.example.helloworld.menu1">
            <separator
                  name="group1">
            </separator>
         </menu>
         <action
               label="Compile Domain Spec"
               class="org.example.helloworld.popup.actions.GenerateVocabularyFramework"
               menubarPath="org.example.helloworld.menu1/group1"
               enablesFor="1"
               id="org.example.helloworld.newAction">
         </action>
         <action
               class="org.example.helloworld.popup.actions.GenerateArchitectureFramework"
               id="org.example.helloworld.action2"
               label="Compile Architecture Spec"
               menubarPath="org.example.helloworld.menu1/group1">
         </action>
         <action
               class="org.example.helloworld.popup.actions.GenerateInteractionFramework"
               id="org.example.helloworld.action3"
               label="Compile User Interaction Spec"
               menubarPath="org.example.helloworld.menu1/group1">
         </action>
         <action
               class="org.example.helloworld.popup.actions.GenerateDeploymentFramework"
               id="org.example.helloworld.action4"
               label="Compile Deployment Spec"
               menubarPath="org.example.helloworld.menu1/group1">
         </action>
      </objectContribution>
   </extension>

</plugin>
```

Comment: Show us how you are defining the menu items in the plugin.xml (or elsewhere)

Comment: With the deprecated `org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus` extension point you can only define visibility for the entire `objectContribution`. The `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension point allows the visibility of individual entries to be set.

Comment: @greg-449 : Thanks for the answer.  But, what could be possible solution in case I continue to use `org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus`. Or pointers for applying `org.eclipse.ui.menus` in the solution.

Comment: Try this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCommands/article.html

Comment: @JonahGraham : thanks for the pointer! I have learned this tutorial. But again problem remains same "How can I enable the specfic menu option based on the my selection"? Kindly refer the question for the detail example on the selection part.

Comment: @Pankesh Unfortunately I am confused, I think @greg-449 has provided good commentary and I have pointed you to the commands tutorial as requested. However, I don't see what you have tried to do with commands in your question. Please explain what you have tried *with commands* as `org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus` does not do what you want.

Comment: As an extra hint, once you finish the basic command tutorial on Vogella's site, follow the recommendation there and continue on to advanced commands.

Comment: You should be looking at the `visibleWhen` element as a child of `command` in the `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension point.